# Data Solutions for Silverlight/Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have an application I'm building for silverlight.  I'm also going to build a UI for windows phone 7 too.  Both will need to have access to data from a database.

Is there one solution that will work on both platforms?  RIA services is out since it's not yet supported in WP7, but can I use a REST or WCF service approach to service both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344728/wp7-binding-listbox-to-wcf-result), WCF on WP7 works fine.